# Why manually install a pre-built python package in Anaconda virtualenv?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

The [Anaconda website](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs) mentions that the installer has 100 of pre-built packages. Even the installer size of 500mb hints that there should be some pre-built packages.

Yet when we want to use any of the packages we have to install them through the command  eg. `conda install nltk`
Which basically downloads the package from internet and then installs it. Which seems counterintuitive since it is *already mentioned on website that nltk is present in the installer.*

Can anybody throw some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts:

- Conda - Package & environment management system.  This gives you the
  `conda` command and serves a similar function as `pip` and
  `virtualenv`.
- Anaconda - Python package distribution containing 100's of scientific
  packages that are tests and verified to work together.

If you install `Miniconda`, you will just get `conda` without the full Anaconda distribution.  If you install `Anaconda`, you will get both the `conda` management system and the Python distribution.  You can also get `Anaconda` after only having installed `conda` by running `conda install Anaconda`.

Comment: I have installed Anaconda only. How am I supposed to take the benefit of the pre-installed packages?

Comment: They'll be installed in your root conda environment.  Are you on Windows or Linux?  Did you select the option to append anaconda to $PATH when installing?  If you run "which python" on Linux or "where python" on Windows does it point to something like `~/anaconda2/bin/python` or `c:\anaconda2\bin\python`?